# Screenshot program over loads RAM

Tags: c#

So i'm relatively new to C# and i want to ride an application that shows you the color of the pixel you hover over but the with this code there seems to be a big problem.
thx a lot for the help
the code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    b = null;
    b = Screenshot();
    Color color = b.GetPixel(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
    label1.Text = color.Name;
    label2.Text = Cursor.Position.Y.ToString() + Cursor.Position.X.ToString();
}

private Bitmap Screenshot()
{
    Bitmap Screen = new Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width,SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Screen);
    g.CopyFromScreen(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.X,SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Y, 0, 0, Screen.Size);
    return Screen;
}
```

Comment: But what's the big problem? can you elaborate further?

Comment: You need to dispose of the Bitmaps when you are done. Where and how do you store them??

Comment: And you don't need to copy the *whole* screen to get a single pixel. In a MouseMove handler, copy a 1x1 bitmap.

Answer (score 2):

You neither need a timer nor copy the whole screen. Just add a MouseMove handler like this:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1))
    {
        var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        var position = PointToScreen(e.Location);
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(position.X, position.Y, 0, 0, new Size(1, 1));
        var color = bitmap.GetPixel(0, 0);

        label1.Text = color.ToString();
    }
}
```

Or reuse the Bitmap:

```
private readonly Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1);

private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
    var position = PointToScreen(e.Location);
    graphics.CopyFromScreen(position.X, position.Y, 0, 0, new Size(1, 1));
    var color = bitmap.GetPixel(0, 0);

    label1.Text = color.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly when you use it in a correct way: *(no global 'b')*

```
private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (var b = Screenshot())
  {
    label1.Text = b.GetPixel(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y).Name;
    label2.Text = Cursor.Position.ToString();
  }
}

private static Bitmap Screenshot()
{
  var Screen = new Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height);
  var g = Graphics.FromImage(Screen);
  g.CopyFromScreen(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.X, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Y, 0, 0, Screen.Size);
  return Screen;
}
```

But of course, try to copy whole screen only for a single pixel is wrong....

Therefore use something like the fixed code from Clemens.

e.g.:

```
private readonly Bitmap screen = new Bitmap(1, 1);
private static readonly Size size = new Size(1, 1);

private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(screen))
  {
    g.CopyFromScreen(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y, 0, 0, size);

    label1.Text = screen.GetPixel(0, 0).Name;
    label2.Text = Cursor.Position.ToString();
  }
}
```

And do not forget to dispose Bitmap in the form Dispose method.